# JAVA: how to input data into a Hashtable using a scanner?

Tags: java, hashtable

I want to be able to enter in a (name, age) into the scanner and store it in a hashtable. so far it is not going well.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Hashtable<String, Integer> names = new Hashtable<String, Integer>();
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        while(in.hasNext()){
            String name = in.nextLine();
            int age = in.nextInt();
            names.put(name, age);
        }
    }
```

Comment: can i add multiple values to a single hashmap?

Comment: yes you can, look at @Daniel's or mine answer bellow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case you want the next token to be read as a String you should use `next()` method and not `nextLine()`. nextLine() returns the line that was skipped not the current line, as you think.

From nextLine() javadoc :

> Advances this scanner past the current line and returns the input that was skipped. This method returns the rest of the current line, excluding any line separator at the end. The position is set to the beginning of the next line. 
>   Since this method continues to search through the input looking for a line separator, it may buffer all of the input searching for the line to skip if no line separators are present.
>   Returns:
>   the line that was skipped

Changing :

`String name = in.nextLine();`

to

`String name = in.next();` will fix your problems. Thats's all you have to do.

Further on, you need some condition to end reading the input. You can use some sort of a keyword, and when that keyword is read you know is time to end reading the input.

A complete and tested example here :

```
private static final String EXIT_KEYWORD = "exit";


public static void main(final String[] args) {
    Hashtable<String, Integer> names = new Hashtable<String, Integer>();
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    while (in.hasNext()) {
        String name = in.next();
        if (EXIT_KEYWORD.equals(name)) {
            break;
        }
        int age = in.nextInt();
        names.put(name, age);
    }

    for (Map.Entry<String, Integer> entry : names.entrySet()) {
        System.out.println(entry.getKey() + " " + entry.getValue());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> public boolean hasNext() Returns true if this scanner has another
>   token in its input. This method may block while waiting for input to
>   scan. The scanner does not advance past any input.

The problem is that you never receive any input because your loop condition never gets resolved. Your program is stuck in `while(in.hasNext())`

You could, for example, pick a word that will end your program, like the string "end" and stop the loop that way. (Another example would be to use a negative value for age to stop the loop)

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Hashtable<String, Integer> names = new Hashtable<String, Integer>();
    String name = "";
    int age = 0;
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    while (true) {
        System.out.println("Enter name:");
        name = in.next();
        if (name.equals("end")) {
            break;
        }
        System.out.println("Enter age:");
        age = Integer.valueOf(in.next());
        names.put(name, age);
    }

    // print the hashtable data
    System.out.println("\nHashtable:\n");
    for(String n : names.keySet()) {
        System.out.println("Name:\t" + n + "\nAge:\t" + names.get(n) + "\n");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Java doc says this about `Scanner.hasnext`

```
public boolean hasNext()
```

Returns true if this scanner has another token in its input. This method may block while waiting for     input to scan. The scanner does not advance past any input.

So your program is waiting at `in.hasNext()`

You can use simple loop with some exit condition to take inputs from console

```
 for(;<exit condition>;)
     // get console inputs
```

Comment: As you've mentioned, the method is blocking until new input is available. When you insert new input, the condition is evaluated to true, so your program is no longer stucked. The problem doesn't come from there.

Answer (score 0):

If you are allowed to choose another pretty way for input format,Please try this:
**Use the input format like this:**
user1:23 user2:33 user3:47
**Output:**
{user3=47, user2=33, user1=23}

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Hashtable<String, Integer> students = new Hashtable<String, Integer>();
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    String line = in.nextLine();
    String[] entries = line.split("\\s+");
    for(String e : entries){
        if(e.contains(":")){
            String[] elements = e.split(":");
            students.put(elements[0], Integer.parseInt(elements[1]));
        }
    }
    System.out.println(students);

}
```

Comment: If you think it is a copy/paste, please attach a link here.For this kind of requirement, first come to my mind is like [key1:value1 key2:value2]. As for the code itself is really 3 minutes thing, no need to search solution for that. :)